# How to remove a duplicated element in a function with a list?

Tags: list, function, haskell, element, ghci

I'm a newbie when it comes to Haskell and I'm confused with a few things. I'm trying to remove duplicated elements in this functions list:

```
qsort :: [Int] -> [Int]
qsort [] = []
qsort (x:xs) = 
     qsort smaller ++ [x] ++ qsort larger
     where 
          smaller = [a | a <- xs, a <= x] 
          larger = [b | b <- xs, b > x]
```

I attempted to do this by importing Data.List and using the nub [] function:

```
qsort :: [Int] -> [Int]
qsort [] = nub[]
```

But, if I do qsort [2, 6, 3, 3], it still returns with [2, 3, 3, 6].

Am I using the nub function wrong or is there something else I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you write `[]` in `qsort [] = nub []`?

Answer (score 1):

Your example shows you only using `nub` on the empty list (`nub []`), which doesn't actually do anything. You have to apply it to the result of the main body of `qsort`:

```
qsort :: [Int] -> [Int]
qsort [] = []
qsort (x:xs) = 
     nub $ qsort smaller ++ [x] ++ qsort larger
     where 
          smaller = [a | a <- xs, a <= x] 
          larger = [b | b <- xs, b > x]
```

This, however, is unnecessarily expensive because it runs `nub` on every branch of the function. Further optimization is left to you.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [@Chad Gilbert's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49007617/how-to-remove-a-duplicated-element-in-a-function-with-a-list/49007970#49007970) answer, you need to apply `nub` on the final sorted list. Unfortunately this function is `O(n^2)`, and would be pretty innefficient if the list gets long.

You can improve the overall complexity to `O(nlogn)`(cost of sorting), if you group identical elements together and just take the first item, which is just an `O(n)` operation.  You can accomplish this with the `map`, `group` and `head` functions.

With these suggestions, here is another way of writing your function:

```
import Data.List

qsort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
qsort [] = []
qsort (pivot:others) = map head $ group $ qsort lowers ++ [pivot] ++ qsort highers
    where lowers = filter (<pivot) others
          highers = filter (>=pivot) others
```

Which works as follows:

```
*Main> qsort [2, 6, 3, 3]
[2,3,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

See the `unique` function in the (Unique)[https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Unique-0.4.7.2/docs/Data-List-Unique.html] package.

```
unique [2,3,6,6,3]
[2,3,6]
```